# fill grid-columns with singularitygs

Tags: singularitygs

is it possible to fill columns in a singularity grid? Here is an example:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/a72ff5f55280b77d1211

What I want is that divs 1,2 and 3 are in the first column and 4 in the second, but 4 should not be next to 3 but to 1. So It should look like this:

```
1 4
2
3
```

I don't really understand how to do that with clears. Or is it only possible by changing the order of my divs?

All the best,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible unless you wrap the first column and second column in their own divs
http://sassmeister.com/gist/ea985c05d5e9527fa485